# How to add ActionBarSherlock to Vanilla Music Player

Tags: android

I am working on a music player app and for reference purpose I have used Vanilla music player source code from [here](https://github.com/kreed/vanilla).
I want to add the ActionBarSherlock to it.
I have imported the Library files into it.
Now, according to the  instructions, I will have to change "_Activity" to "_SherlockActivity". But I have a class LibraryActivity which extends PlaybackActivity. I am not getting how to add SherlockActivity to this class. Can anyone suggest me some method.

For those who didn't understood the above question, I just want to add ABS to Vanilla music.
I have the main LibraryActivity as follows:
http://pastebin.com/bFs96uBK

Comment: no reply to my link dear..I was think you feel not good, but you are active here.

Answer (score 0):

LibraryActivity is extending PlaybackActivity which is just another class in the project.

Open PlaybackActivity class instead and extend SherlockActivity from it.